# Removing an item from list matching a substring

Tags: python, list, substring, string-matching

How do I remove an element from a list if it matches a substring?

I have tried removing an element from a list using the `pop()` and `enumerate` method but seems like I'm missing a few contiguous items that needs to be removed:

```
sents = ['@$\tthis sentences needs to be removed', 'this doesnt',
     '@$\tthis sentences also needs to be removed',
     '@$\tthis sentences must be removed', 'this shouldnt',
     '# this needs to be removed', 'this isnt',
     '# this must', 'this musnt']

for i, j in enumerate(sents):
  if j[0:3] == "@$\t":
    sents.pop(i)
    continue
  if j[0] == "#":
    sents.pop(i)

for i in sents:
  print i
```

Output:

```
this doesnt
@$  this sentences must be removed
this shouldnt
this isnt
#this should
this musnt
```

Desired output:

```
this doesnt
this shouldnt
this isnt
this musnt
```

Comment: Classic case of removing items from a list while you're iterating over that list.  Read the dozens of other Stack Overflow questions that relate to this.  Also, see the [note in the docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#for).

Comment: you should always avoid changing the length of a container while iterating through it, this is a recipe for disaster

Comment: In general, it's usually better to create a new filtered list than to try to modify a list in-place. Immutable algorithms are always easier to reason through (although not always easier to figure out how to write). When you're just replacing values, sometimes the efficiency gains of working in-place beat that, but when you're deleting or inserting in the middle of a list, you're usually getting _worse_ efficiency along with your less robust logic.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

How about something simple like:

```
>>> [x for x in sents if not x.startswith('@$\t') and not x.startswith('#')]
['this doesnt', 'this shouldnt', 'this isnt', 'this musnt']
```

Answer (score 20):

This should work:

```py
[i for i in sents if not ('@$\t' in i or '#' in i)]
```

If you want only things that begin with those specified sentential use the `str.startswith(stringOfInterest)` method

```py
[i for i in sents if i.startswith('#')]
```

Comment: I'd argue this one is better than the other two for not assuming the substrings are at the start

Comment: FYI -- if you get a `NoneType` Error, when using this CHECK YOUR VALUES and be sure to remove any `<class 'NoneType'>` values in your list.  see: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-remove-none-values-from-list/

Answer (score 15):

Another technique using `filter`

```
filter( lambda s: not (s[0:3]=="@$\t" or s[0]=="#"), sents)
```

The problem with your orignal approach is when you're on list item `i` and determine it should be deleted, you remove it from the list, which slides the `i+1` item into the `i` position. The next iteration of the loop you're at index `i+1` but the item is actually `i+2`.

Make sense?

Comment: thanks for the explanation! popping a list while enumerating is silly indeed. hahaha..

Comment: Only this worked for me:

    sents = list(filter( lambda s: not (s[0:3]=="@$\t" or s[0]=="#"), sents))