# How to delete a list item if it contains a certain string?

Tags: python, list

I have the following list:

```
['Nome (Admilson Monteiro Garcia)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Marcio Hamilton Ferreira)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Marco Antonio Da Silva Barros)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Nilson Martiniano Moreira)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Walter Malieni Junior)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Antonio Pedro Da Silva Machado)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Paulo Rogerio Caffarelli)', 'Qualificação (16-Presidente)',
 'Nome (Adriano Meira Ricci)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Carlos Alberto Araujo Netto)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Antonio Mauricio Maurano)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Osmar Fernandes Dias)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Marcelo Augusto Dutra Labuto)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Hideraldo Dwight Leitao)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Leonardo Silva de Loyola Reis)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Rogerio Magno Panca)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Simao Luiz Kovalski)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Tarcisio Hubner)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Eduardo Cesar Pasa)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Marcio Luiz Moral)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Wilsa Figueiredo)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Jose Eduardo Moreira Bergo)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Alexandre Alves de Souza)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Cicero Przendsiuk)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Edmar Jose Casalatina)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Edson Pascoal Cardozo)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Edson Rogerio Da Costa)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Fabiano Macanhan Fontes)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Fernando Florencio Campos)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Gustavo de Souza Fosse)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Marco Tulio de Oliveira Mendonca)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Marvio Melo Freitas)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Reinaldo Kazufumi Yokoyama)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Jose Caetano de Andrade Minchillo)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Carlos Renato Bonetti)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Marco Antonio Ascoli Mastroeni)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Alberto Monteiro de Queiroz Netto)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Jose Eduardo Pereira Filho)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Marco Tulio Moraes Da Costa)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Joao Pinto Rabelo Junior)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)',
 'Nome (Carlos Hamilton Vasconcelos Araujo)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)']
```

I want to delete all items that have the string `'Qualificação` in them. Is there a way to do that without a `for` loop?

Comment: Rather than mutating the list, you could use a comprehension to build up a new list. Something like `my_list = [item for item in my_list if not 'Qualificação' in item]`

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666897/removing-an-item-from-list-matching-a-substring-python

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953253/searching-for-substring-in-element-in-a-list-an-deleting-the-element-python

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter`:

```
d = ['Nome (Admilson Monteiro Garcia)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Marcio Hamilton Ferreira)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Marco Antonio Da Silva Barros)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Nilson Martiniano Moreira)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Walter Malieni Junior)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Antonio Pedro Da Silva Machado)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Paulo Rogerio Caffarelli)', 'Qualificação (16-Presidente)', 'Nome (Adriano Meira Ricci)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Carlos Alberto Araujo Netto)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Antonio Mauricio Maurano)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Osmar Fernandes Dias)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Marcelo Augusto Dutra Labuto)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Hideraldo Dwight Leitao)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Leonardo Silva de Loyola Reis)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Rogerio Magno Panca)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Simao Luiz Kovalski)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Tarcisio Hubner)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Eduardo Cesar Pasa)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Marcio Luiz Moral)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Wilsa Figueiredo)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Jose Eduardo Moreira Bergo)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Alexandre Alves de Souza)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Cicero Przendsiuk)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Edmar Jose Casalatina)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Edson Pascoal Cardozo)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Edson Rogerio Da Costa)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Fabiano Macanhan Fontes)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Fernando Florencio Campos)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Gustavo de Souza Fosse)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Marco Tulio de Oliveira Mendonca)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Marvio Melo Freitas)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Reinaldo Kazufumi Yokoyama)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Jose Caetano de Andrade Minchillo)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Carlos Renato Bonetti)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Marco Antonio Ascoli Mastroeni)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Alberto Monteiro de Queiroz Netto)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Jose Eduardo Pereira Filho)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Marco Tulio Moraes Da Costa)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Joao Pinto Rabelo Junior)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)', 'Nome (Carlos Hamilton Vasconcelos Araujo)', 'Qualificação (10-Diretor)']
new_d = list(filter(lambda x:'Qualificação' not in x, d))
```

Output:

```
['Nome (Admilson Monteiro Garcia)', 'Nome (Marcio Hamilton Ferreira)', 'Nome (Marco Antonio Da Silva Barros)', 'Nome (Nilson Martiniano Moreira)', 'Nome (Walter Malieni Junior)', 'Nome (Antonio Pedro Da Silva Machado)', 'Nome (Paulo Rogerio Caffarelli)', 'Nome (Adriano Meira Ricci)', 'Nome (Carlos Alberto Araujo Netto)', 'Nome (Antonio Mauricio Maurano)', 'Nome (Osmar Fernandes Dias)', 'Nome (Marcelo Augusto Dutra Labuto)', 'Nome (Hideraldo Dwight Leitao)', 'Nome (Leonardo Silva de Loyola Reis)', 'Nome (Rogerio Magno Panca)', 'Nome (Simao Luiz Kovalski)', 'Nome (Tarcisio Hubner)', 'Nome (Eduardo Cesar Pasa)', 'Nome (Marcio Luiz Moral)', 'Nome (Wilsa Figueiredo)', 'Nome (Jose Eduardo Moreira Bergo)', 'Nome (Alexandre Alves de Souza)', 'Nome (Cicero Przendsiuk)', 'Nome (Edmar Jose Casalatina)', 'Nome (Edson Pascoal Cardozo)', 'Nome (Edson Rogerio Da Costa)', 'Nome (Fabiano Macanhan Fontes)', 'Nome (Fernando Florencio Campos)', 'Nome (Gustavo de Souza Fosse)', 'Nome (Marco Tulio de Oliveira Mendonca)', 'Nome (Marvio Melo Freitas)', 'Nome (Reinaldo Kazufumi Yokoyama)', 'Nome (Jose Caetano de Andrade Minchillo)', 'Nome (Carlos Renato Bonetti)', 'Nome (Marco Antonio Ascoli Mastroeni)', 'Nome (Alberto Monteiro de Queiroz Netto)', 'Nome (Jose Eduardo Pereira Filho)', 'Nome (Marco Tulio Moraes Da Costa)', 'Nome (Joao Pinto Rabelo Junior)', 'Nome (Carlos Hamilton Vasconcelos Araujo)']
```